# How to use Multiple Taskpane in Excel add-in using OfficeJS

Tags: excel, office-js

We are using two taskpane's in Excel add-in. Our scenario is if we apply same **taskpaneID** for those two then each of those taskpane is getting reloaded with updated data in initial and subsequent command clicks. But if we apply unique **taskpaneID** then on initial click event, it is getting loaded taskpane but subsequent click of same each, it is showing with cached data without loading refreshed data. We wanted to achieve the second scenario in our application. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Do you want to implement multiple Ribbon to launch the multiple taskpane?

Comment: Yes. I was able to do but not able to reload the data for respective taskpane opening based on ribbon command clicks..